# Adding a new user to Django, by directly writing in the DB

Tags: django, django-models, user-management

I need to programmatically add a new user to a Django setup from a 3rd party platform (PHP) and it seems that I only need to write a single entry in the `auth_user` table to achieve this.

Am I correct? Do I need to do something else also?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes,  you could write the data directly into the `auth_user ` table. Note that you'll need to hash the password in the same format Django uses. If the site has user profiles,  you might to add the associated data to whatever the profile table is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, assuming you don't mind re-implementing the things that Django does for you; particularly hashing the password, but possibly also creating a `UserProfile` object as Ignacio suggests. You'd also need to work out another solution for code relying on `post_save` or `pre_save` signals in your project (if there is any).

You haven't explained *why* you want to do things this way: what is dictating that you can't have any inter-process communication apart from shared access to an SQL database?

If you can do things differently, it might make more sense to set up a localhost-only API endpoint to create users, either using [the included `UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) or [the `create_user()` helper method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user).

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but there may be other requirements such as creating a `UserProfile` which are governed by business logic and not the database. Perhaps you should consider creating the user in a separate table/database and writing a custom authentication backend which imports users from this shared location.

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would re think your approach. In My opinion you risk data integrity issues and hard to find bugs by messing with django's tables whilst bypassing its proven business logic.  I would approach this by writing a simple API  in django which you expose to you php script that will allow django to add the users on php's behalf. This May actually turn out to be a simpler approach anyway in terms of coding time and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It working for me in PHP.

```
/*
 *
 * DJANGO AUTH
 * https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/
 * <algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
 * 
*/

function genRandomString($length = 32) {
    $retval = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        $retval .= chr(rand(97,122));
    }
    return $retval;
}

$algo = 'sha256';
$password = 'your_password_here';
$salt = genRandomString(12);
$iteration = 180000;

$hash_password = base64_encode(hash_pbkdf2($algo, $password, $salt, $iteration, 32, true));
$link_for_db = 'pbkdf2_' . $algo . '$' . $iteration . '$' . $salt . '$' . $hash_password;
var_dump($link_for_db); //pbkdf2_sha256$180000$u02p8yhQmV3d$AOX+AZQmxe9gwlJaQn1P0f6rrOht7o9cVCY0nG5xa3g=
```